# Ansible access Azure credentials while using the credentials file and the azure_rm_resource module

Tags: azure, ansible

While I am using ansible to create some infrastructure on Azure, I am trying to access the `subscritpion_id` during an ansible run. I setup the credentials file following the 
the Azure guide from the ansible documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html

When I run the ansible playbook I am adding the following argument `-e ANSIBLE_PROFILE="new-env"` which does what it needs to do and provide the proper credentials for the run to execute the module correctly.

But I am trying to use the Azure REST API through the `azure_rm_resource` module and I want to send a JSON representation in the body of the request which would include the `subscription_id` to format the id of a resource in Azure.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/azure_rm_resource_module.html

Lets say a VNet ID in Azure looks like `"id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet",`
I am able to format the name of the vnet but I need to get the information of the subscription id which is read by ansible from the `~/.azure/credentials` file during the playbook run.

How do I access this information? Is there a special variable? I looked into the `lookup env` feature and it is not there with the variable `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`.

It is not either in the facts I tried the expose the facts using the following command `AZURE_PROFILE="new-env" ansible localhost -m setup`

Credentials file example

```
    cat ~/.azure/credentials

    [new-env]
    subscription_id=****************************
    client_id=****************************
    secret=****************************
    tenant=****************************
```

Thanks

**UPDATE #1**

I ended up using the ansible ini lookup feature.

```
     "{{ lookup('ini',  'subscription_id section={{ azure_profile }}  file={{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.azure/credentials') }}"
```

This is returning the exact value I was looking for and I use a `set_fact` to set it through my ansible run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ini lookup I am searching straight in the credentials file and then I set it as a fact to re-use it later on.

```
tasks:

    - name: set fact to reduce the verbosity of the variables
      set_fact:
        azure_profile: "{{ AZURE_PROFILE }}"
        azure_subscription_id: "{{ lookup('ini',  'subscription_id section={{ azure_profile }}  file={{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.azure/credentials') }}"
```